# How to calculate asymptotic convergence of 2D data

Tags: plotting, functions, data

I have the following data:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.0000598696, 0.1}, {0.000239558, 0.2}, {0.000539305, 
  0.3}, {0.00095951, 0.4}, {0.00150074, 0.5}, {0.00216372, 
  0.6}, {0.00294935, 0.7}, {0.0038587, 0.8}, {0.00489312, 
  0.9}, {0.00605393, 1}, {0.00734283, 1.1}, {0.00876167, 
  1.2}, {0.0103125, 1.3}, {0.0119977, 1.4}, {0.0138197, 
  1.5}, {0.0157815, 1.6}, {0.017886, 1.7}, {0.0201367, 
  1.8}, {0.0225373, 1.9}, {0.0250919, 2}, {0.0278051, 
  2.1}, {0.0306816, 2.2}, {0.033727, 2.3}, {0.0369471, 
  2.4}, {0.0403485, 2.5}, {0.0439382, 2.6}, {0.0477242, 
  2.7}, {0.0517152, 2.8}, {0.0559207, 2.9}, {0.0603515, 
  3}, {0.0650195, 3.1}, {0.0699378, 3.2}, {0.0751215, 
  3.3}, {0.0805873, 3.4}, {0.0863541, 3.5}, {0.0924755, 
  3.6}, {0.0989219, 3.7}, {0.105747, 3.8}, {0.112985, 3.9}, {0.120675,
   4}, {0.128866, 4.1}, {0.137615, 4.2}, {0.146991, 4.3}, {0.157081, 
  4.4}, {0.168113, 4.5}, {0.180044, 4.6}, {0.193157, 4.7}, {0.207727, 
  4.8}, {0.224426, 4.9}, {0.243798, 5}, {0.267247, 5.1}, {0.298384, 
  5.2}, {0.358415, 5.3}, {2.10175, 5.35}};
```

I can plot it:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

And I get:

[image]

As you can see, the data slowly converges to a certain $ y $ value. How can I calculate that converged height $ y_{\text c} $ ?

Comment: I do not think you have enough data to be able to make a good guess on asymptotics.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I updated my question with more data points.

Comment: If you have knowledge of the system, you can make some assumptions. For example, if it's a linear first-order system, you could try to fit the data in typical generic response of such a system using `FindFit[data, a (1 - Exp[-k t]), {a, k}, t]`.

Comment: It is not quite convincing that the data goes to a horizontal asymptotics. Indeed, if you do not use the option `Joined->True` you will see that there is a huge gap between the very last and the previous points and that the abscissa of the previous one is 5.3, while that of the last one is 5.35. It is, of course, up to you if you consider the abscissa difference of 0.05 to already be negligible. If you do, then try `Max[Transpose[data][[2]]]` which will return 5.35.

Comment: As @ercegovac states, you'll need to "know" the form of the underlying model.  With data as smooth as you have (`ListLogLogPlot[data]`), certainly there must be some expected form of the theoretical model.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, as pointed out in the comments, is to fit to a model using non-linear regression.

For example,  `data1` may be fitted to a [rectangular hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics), where $Y_\text{max}$ it the asymptotic value of $y$, and $X_\text{half}$ is the value of $x$ at half the asymptotic value of $y$.

$$y=\frac{{ Y_{max} x}}{x+X_{\text{half}}}$$

`FindFit` will do the job, but `NonLinearFitModel` gives more information.

```
 fm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data, (Ymax x)/(Xhalf + x), {Ymax, Xhalf}, x];
```

and

```
fm1[{"BestFitParameters", "ParameterErrors"}]
```

> {{Ymax -> 5.60917, Xhalf -> 0.0455176}, {0.0787277, 0.00212893}}

Fit of model to data

```
Show[Plot[fm1["BestFit"], {x, 0, 2.45}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: Michaelis Plot of data]

One of the predictions of the chosen model is that a plot of $1/y$ vs $1/x$ will
be linear with a $y$-axis intercept of $1/Y_{max}$ (statistically [a very poor plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineweaver%E2%80%93Burk_plot)).  As the following shows, this is not true for `data`, indicating a bad choice of model.

```
ListPlot[({1/#1, 1/#2} & @@@ Rest@data), PlotRange -> {{0, 2000}, {0, 4}}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Lineweaver-Burk plot]